# How does `cin>>` take three values though they are separated by space?

Tags: c++, input, cin

When looking at some code online I found

```
cin>>arr[0][0]>>arr[0][1]>>arr[0][2]
```

where I put a line of three integer values separated by space. I see that those three integers separated by space become the value of `arr[0][0]`, `arr[0][1]` and `arr[0][2]`.

It doesn't cause any trouble if there are more than one space between them.

**plz, can anyone explain me how this work?**

Comment: `operator>>` returns `istream&` Think of it like `((cin >> a) >> b) >> c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading almost any types of inputs from a stream will skip any leading whitespaces first, unless you explicitly turn that feature off. You should read [`std::basic_istream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) documentation for more information:

> Extracts an integer value potentially skipping preceding whitespace. The value is stored to a given reference value.
>
> This function behaves as a [`FormattedInputFunction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction). After constructing and checking the sentry object, which may skip leading whitespace, extracts an integer value by calling [`std::num_get::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get).

The same applies to other stream input functions, including the [`scanf` family](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) where most format specifiers will consume all whitespace characters before reading the value:

> All conversion specifiers other than `[`, `c`, and `n` consume and discard all leading whitespace characters (determined as if by calling [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace)) before attempting to parse the input. These consumed characters do not count towards the specified maximum field width.

Answer (score 1):

Most overloads of `operator>>` consume and discard all whitespace characters first thing. They begin parsing the actual value (say, an `int`) starting from the first non-whitespace character in the stream.